# Selenium Browser gives me exception of element not be scrolled into view without using WebDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, browser

I tested my code line by line and it works in the Python3 environment
But when I execute in script my code it can't click a simple button.

The HTML of the button:

input value="Button_validation" type="button" style""

In my script after executing several Brower().find and do :

```
From Selenium Import Browser

browser=Browser()

[...]

browser.wait_time = 15

browser.find_by_value('Button_validation').first.click()

browser.quit()
```

When I execute the script it stops in this lines saying:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  could not be scrolled into view

It works fine in commands but in script doesn't work, I don't want to write more lines of code, I don't want to use WebDriver, I am happy using Brower but no one in the web seems to have this issue.

Hope some one could help me.

geckodriver 27
Python 3.4
Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to all, I had suspicions that all the trouble was due the rendering time of the website and it was, strangely I added a wait_time=20 and that couldn't solve it.

while (browser.is_element_not_present_by_xpath(xpath='//*[@id="easy_answer"]',wait_time=2)):
        os.system("echo waiting to render")

The echo is not working, but with this loop the script waits until the element is present, that means when everything is clickable.

Hope This Helps!